# Dealing with collections with Parent -Child relationships in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, collections

I'm having a problem with finding out which children to add, update and delete when I'm dealing with two lists one with the old chidren (from db) and the other list with the modified children (from user input).

Currently I have to loop through the lists and compare to find the difference.

Does anyone know of a better way of doing this without having to loop through the lists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [IEnumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356791.aspx) extension method is perfect for this. In most cases you will want to use the overload that accepts an `IEqualityComparer<T>` to compare by identity, unless you have carefully overridden Equals and GetHashCode in your objects.

Given

```
IEnumerable<Company> oldList, IEnumerable<Company> newList
```

The code is:

```
var companiesToAdd = newList.Except(oldList).ToArray();
var companiesToRemove = oldList.Except(newList).ToArray();
```

The `ToArray()` calls are there so that you can make changes to the original list while iterating the add and remove lists.

Edit: Below are two utility classes that make this operation easy. Usage is

```
var diff = new DiffIEnumerable<Company>(oldList, newList, x => x.CompanyId);
var companiesToAdd = diff.InYNotX;
var companiesToRemove = diff.InXNotY;
```

---

```
public class IdentityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly Func<T, object> _getIdentity;

    public IdentityComparer(Func<T, object> getIdentity)
    {
        _getIdentity = getIdentity;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return _getIdentity(x).Equals(_getIdentity(y));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return _getIdentity(obj).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class DiffIEnumerable<T> where T : class
{
    public DiffIEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y, Func<T, object> getIdentity) :
        this(x, y, new IdentityComparer<T>(getIdentity))
    { }

    public DiffIEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        InXAndY = x.Intersect(y, comparer).ToArray();
        InXNotY = x.Except(y, comparer).ToArray();
        InYNotX = y.Except(x, comparer).ToArray();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> InXAndY { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<T> InXNotY { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<T> InYNotX { get; private set; }

}
```

Comment: That's pretty slick..will be adding this to my bag-o-tricks +1